# How to get an extent for Raster using python

Tags: raster, arcpy, clip, extents

I have to get an extent of a given raster so that I can save it and use the same to clip another raster with that extracted extent. As of now I am stuck in the extent part.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env


desc= arcpy.env.extent("D:\GIS @ UTD\Sem 1\GISC 6317\Lab\Lab 10\temp\Tahoe\Tahoe\Emer\erelev.grid")

print desc
```

The following gives an output 0 0 0 0 NaN NaN NaN NaN.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Dont use `env.extent` you need to get raster extent.

```
import arcpy

elevRaster = arcpy.sa.Raster('C:/data/elevation')
myExtent = elevRaster.extent

print myExtent
```

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following script, which should work... Please change the path as per the location (Either in Geodatabase or Folders). In this example 'congrd' is the raster dataset that I used.

```
import arcpy

from arcpy.sa import *

elevRaster = Raster('C:/arcgis/ArcTutor/3DAnalyst/Exercise2/workspace2/congrd')

myExtent = elevRaster.extent

print myExtent
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: -1 This is effectively the same answer as the one posted by @Aragon.

Comment: I tried yours and it failed...That is why I had posted the tweaked one...I guess "import arcpy" alone cannot do the trick. Sometimes we need a little push.

Comment: @JeganSomu You can always edit existing answer instead of creating barely different one. If you don't have enough points, your edits will be reviewed first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Describe:

```
import arcpy
rasterfile = r"C:\folder\photo.tif"
d = arcpy.Describe(rasterfile)
ext = d.extent

<Extent object at 0x1fc6aea9708[0x1fc302a0f30]>
```