# Why use " from arcpy.sa import * "

Tags: python, arcpy

Previously on the following post:

[How to get an extent for Raster using python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41680/how-to-get-an-extent-for-raster-using-python/41798#41798)

A user edited the original Python script by adding the following code:

```
from arcpy.sa import *
```

Why did he do this and what exactly is it doing?
I also received an error when I tried running the original script w/o the edit.

Comment: Read more on "[In python, why is “import *” bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/in-python-why-is-import-bad)" and the ["Idioms and Anti-Idioms in Python"](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/howto/doanddont.html#at-module-level) where it states _"While it is valid to use from module import * at module level it is usually a bad idea [...] You [...] open yourself to trouble in the future, if some module grows additional functions or classes."_

Answer (score 7):

I will take a stab at this.  That line is what is called an import statement in Python.  This basically tells python to go load all the modules in the arcpy.sa path.

Here is more about the important statement:

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/import.html

Here is the path that Python know about to load the modules if you have a default install:

C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa

So in short that statement just tells Python were to find the spatial analyst classes that you are using in your Python file.

Additional Info:

Here is a pretty good explanation from the technical side.

http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath

The reason you received an error without it is that Python did not know where to find the class you are trying to use.

Answer (score 4):

The main reason ESRI suggests doing this is to import all the overloaded operators for use in raster algebra. If you aren't using them then just import sa by itself.

Comment: This is a good point, which my comment above did not really cover.  In the [online help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00p600000016000000) itself, it says _"Using this import method makes it possible to access Spatial Analyst functionality without providing a name space and imports overloaded operators, which allows rasters to be used with operators."_  It certainly saves you a lot of un-needed typing.

Comment: Yes. That documentese sentence about _"Using this import method..."_ is an overly vague way of saying "do this because then your Python code will look like old-style map algebra."

Comment: @JasonScheirer I think you should provide that as a separate Answer (and also drop a note to the documenter:-)

Comment: Still bad practice :)

Comment: @NathanW Hence not posting as an answer

Comment: What this question needs is a shakey analogy. Modules that ask you to import * are like people who monopolize a conversation and only talk about themselves. Also not true about the operators: they're methods of the objects (\_\_add\_\_, \_\_mult\_\_ etc) not names in the module.